# Identifying Corrupt files in win7

Tags: windows-7, usb, filesystems

I have some files on an external partition which appear to be corrupt/have bad sectors - ie when I try to copy them, the copy process hangs around forever without seeming to do anything. Unfortunately these are mixed in  with a large number of files that are perfectly  fine. Is there a way to identify the bad files other than trial and error so I can retrieve the good ones in one go?

Many thanks in advance

Joe

Comment: I would run Spinrite6 on the hard drive, it will repair bad sectors and save your data....http://www.grc.com/intro.htm

Comment: Again, thanks for this, but I am not looking to do data recovery right now - I am okay with loosing the bad files, I just need to identify the good ones, so I can keep them Thanks for the app info tho.

Comment: I would look for a copy program that can skip corrupt files, so the copy progress will continue, don't know of one off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/86-find-all-corrupted-files-and-folders-on-the-hard-drive describes how to do EXACTLY that ... and robocopy is on your computer already if you have win7 or vista, and there is a link to download it should you have xp

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged as URLs tend to break with time. You should at least summarize the important part in your answer. Giving the link as reference for further reading is great, anyway.